# EntityFramework .SaveChanges() Invalid Column exception. Why is it appending a '1' to column name?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model with 3 properties (`Id, Name, Menu_Id`) posting from a form.  Everything seems to be passing through fine but when I hit the `SaveChanges()` call I get an exception saying that there is no column named `Menu_Id1`.  It seems like somewhere in the line EF is appending the number '1' to the column name.  I'm not able to step-through into `SaveChanges()` so I can't see where it's happening (Not sure if that's because I'm using VS 2012 Express or not).

Comment: Double-check how you setup your mapping to your database.

Comment: you should update your entity data model to be sure that it's the same as in your database.

Comment: this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915814/entity-framework-invalid-column-name-ef-adds-numer-1-to-primary-key