# SqlException: Invalid column name 'ClientId1'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

Got a table in SQL Server with a ClientId (int, foreign key). Run the program, everything fine.
Renamed the column to ClientID (capitals ID). After importing the model ASP.NET MVC Core

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP-XYZ;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force
```

and run the program, I get the error Invalid column name 'ClientId1'.

- In the whole project ClientId1 is not found
- Rebuild does not work
- Adding ClientId1 (temporary) to the database will give an error about 'ClientId2', etc. ...
- Drop create database won't work
- Exit/Start VS2017 has no effect
- SQL Server profiler shows a statement with 'ClientId1'

Get the error on a simple statement (for the table I made the change):

```
var projectList = await context.Project.ToListAsync();
```

The SQL Server profiler shows

```
SELECT [p].[ID], [p].[ClientID], [p].[ClientId1], [p].[Description], [p].[ExpirationDate], [p].[ImageDirectory], [p].[Name], [p].[Price], [p].[Size], [p].[StartDate], [p].[StatusID], ... 
FROM [Project] AS [p]
```

The (correctly) generated Project class looks like (there is no ClientId1):

```
...
public int Id { get; set; }
public int? ClientId { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
public string ImageDirectory { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
public int Size { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public int StatusId { get; set; }
...
```

How to solve this, thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you querying? We need to see your code. Your model classes, would probably help too.

Comment: Added the statement that fails

Comment: Re `SQL Server profiler shows a statement with 'ClientId1'` - actual statement would be more informative.

Comment: And now the `Project` entity definition please

Comment: Profiler textdata added and Project entity. When I create a new VS2017 project, Scaffold-DbContext, execute the await context.Project.ToListAsync(); everthing works fine. But as it is quite a project...

Comment: Might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348019/entity-framework-appending-1-to-property-name-when-it-matches-entity-name or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915814/entity-framework-invalid-column-name-ef-adds-numer-1-to-primary-key/22231679

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the renaming of the column. In about the same period a property was added to the NOT generated partial Client class:

```
public partial class Client
{
    ...
    public List<Project> ProjectList { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This seems to confuse Linq. Needed is an extra [NoMapped] DataAnnotation. So the following code will work.

```
public partial class Client
{
    ...
    [NoMapped]
    public List<Project> ProjectList { get; set; }
    ...
}
```